# How to await a WebSocket response in gatling without sending a message

Tags: kotlin, websocket, gatling

I'm working with WebSockets in Gatling and have a slight issue in that I get multiple responses with the same message and different values, but the original message is sent only once. The subsequent web socket responses are triggered by a graphql post.

Obviously `.exec(ws("Web Socket Request").await(5)` doesn't work so Im wondering how I would `await` and `check` the subsequent message?

You can see the requests in dev console here. Message with `"id": "11"` is sent and message with `"id": "11"` is received, then another one (`"id": "11"`) is received after the graphql call.

[image]

So my code currently looks like this:

```
        .exec(graphQlRequests.onlineStatus(false))
        .exec(graphQlRequests.chatRooms())
        .exec(
            ws("Video Watch").sendText(subscriptionQueries.videoWatch()).await(5)
                .on(ws.checkTextMessage("Video Watch").check(jsonPath("\$..choices[0].id")
                    .saveAs("choice")))
        )
        .exec(ws("New Messages").sendText(subscriptionQueries.newMessages()))
        .pause(1)
        .exec(graphQlRequests.startVideo())
        .exec(graphQlRequests.chatRoom())
        .exec(graphQlRequests.onlineStatus(false))
        .exec(graphQlRequests.chatRoom())
        .exec(graphQlRequests.onlineStatus(true))
        .pause(9)
        .exec(graphQlRequests.onlineStatus(true))
        .pause(3)
        .exec(graphQlRequests.videoChoice())
        // Capture the second WebSocket message here.....
        .exec(graphQlRequests.onlineStatus(true))
        .pause(15)
        .exec(graphQlRequests.onlineStatus(false))
```

What is the best way to capture the second request? Do I need to open up a separate SSE connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a similar issue as https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3809.

In short, the expected WebSocket inbound message might have already been received between your HTTP request and your WebSocket await, so the latter misses it.

You're welcome to help with specifying a proper solution on our bug tracker (but no "upvote", "me too" or "+1" please, it doesn't help in any way and doesn't make things happen faster).

Comment: Hi Stephane, 

Thanks for replying. I had a look at the issue and I don't think its quite the same as my case. Apologies for saying the "same message". It's two different messages with different data but the same JSON structure. 

The scenario is user choice in the 1st case which sends a ws msg and you get the first response. User make 2nd choice, but the choice is sent via a graphql post, then another ws msg is sent back from the server.

My issue isn't a race condition. It's how to capture the 2nd received msg as it's triggered via an API call, not an outgoing WS request?

Comment: That's completely related. When we revamped the WebSocket support, we didn't keep `ws("Web Socket Request").await(5)` because of this race condition. We'll only reintroduce it once we have a proper design for it.